# Extracting Email Address from Microsoft Exchange

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, powershell, active-directory, exchange

We have a Microsoft Exchange server that has a lot of email address information for all of our Active Directory Users. What would be the best way to pull that email list so that I can attached it to a Active Directory's user account. ( I know how to import into AD ) I just don't know how to export information from Microsoft exchange without the Exchange Management Shell.

I do not have access to the Exchange Management Shell nor do I know how to get it. I was thinking there was some way of doing it by Power-Shell/C#, but honestly i'm not sure what I would be calling to even start. Does anyone have any ideas or even something I can read to get started?

Comment: The EMS *is* PowerShell...

Comment: "...so that I can attached it to a Active Directory's user account." Please clarify what you mean by "attach" the email address to the AD account.

Comment: Why would you not be able to get access to the EMS if you need that information?

Comment: I am assuming that the pull would come in a csv format. With that I was going to populate my user ad accounts with their email in the attribute editor (mail) since a good bit of my users do not have their email in there.

Comment: @TwistyImpersonator I thought to use the EMS you need to be on the actual Exchange Server. I could be wrong and if I am please let me know. I know nothing about Exchange hints why I asked about something to read :).

Comment: You can either install the EMS on a machine or use it through PowerShell remoting (this will limit some of the objects). If a user object is connected to a mailbox there are more attributes necessary than just the mail address. So make sure what you're looking at and what you want to do. See also [`Connect-Mailbox`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/mailboxes/connect-mailbox?view=exchange-ps).

Comment: Check out https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/exchange/exchange-server/connect-to-exchange-servers-using-remote-powershell

Answer (score 0):

Exchange management shell is just powershell that's loaded with the Microsoft.exchange module/configuration. You can use powershell to tap into exchange by using the commands in the below link;

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/exchange/exchange-eop/connect-to-exchange-online-protection-powershell?view=exchange-ps

I use this frequently when I don't need to go into the mail server but you have to ensure that PSRemoting is enabled and there are a few other prerequisites that need to be setup detailed in the link. You might have to switch authentication method depending on how your AD authentication is setup (Kerberos/basic is most common)

Other than this, you can export a list from exchange in the Recipient configuration -> mailbox section and on the right-hand pane there is an export list function. This exports the display name, OU, mailbox type, email address etc. and then you should be able to format this in a way you'd like it, but it's not as granular as the powershell method where you can specify exactly what you want exporting.

Also, if you can define a logic for the users email address, you could just use a powershell script to import the email addresses into AD if it follows a consistent format of for example, firstname.surname@company.co.uk, so no need to even touch the mail server in this method. If this is the case, you would need to use a ForEach-object import and then query AD to pull each first name, surname and then concatenate these strings into an import function to show 
"$Firstname, $Surname"@company.co.uk which will loop through each user and apply the e-mail address using the Set-ADUser cmdlet.

Answer (score 0):

If you can access the Exchange admin center, you can also export the SMTP email addresses from the EAC, which will provide the UI to export the data.

[image]

[image]